# Looking for ideal kernel NW estimate in R

Tags: r, kernel-density

The problem is simple. I have covariate `x` and some outcome `y` and I would like to find Nadarya-Watson estimate of `y` based on `x`. However, I would like to find a function which satisfies several conditions:

1. Besides estimate it returns also weights
2. It handles not only uniformly distributed points for which the estimate is provided.
3. It is reasonably fast.

I can simply implement it by myself. My naive estimate function than looks something like this:

```
mNW <- function(x, X, Y, h, K = dnorm) {

  # Arguments
  # x: evaluation points
  # X: covariates
  # Y: outcome
  # h: bandwidth
  # K: kernel

  Kx <- sapply(X, function(Xi) K((x - Xi) / h))

  # Weights
  W <- Kx / rowSums(Kx) 

  # NW estimate
  m <- W %*% Y

  return(list(m = m, W = W))
}

set.seed(123)
X <- rnorm(1000)
Y <- 1 + X - 2*X^2 + rnorm(1000)
x <- c(-3, -2.1, -0.7, 0, 0.3, 0.8, 1, 1.9, 3.2)

mNW(x, X, Y, h = 0.5)
```

It works fine but it is slow. So I have tried to find something already implemented. First choice was `kernsmooth`:

```
ksmooth(X, Y, kernel = "normal", bandwidth = 0.5, x.points = x)
```

This one is faster, however it does not return weights. Moreover, it only uses `"box"` and `"normal"` kernels.

I have also tried `locpoly` from `KernSmooth` package:

```
locpoly(X, Y, drv = 0, kernel = "normal", bandwidth = 0.5, 
        gridsize = 9, range.x = c(-3, 3.2))
```

Besides it does not return weights, I was not able to run function for my own specification of `x` and I had to use equally spaced values in some specified range.

So I am wondering if there is something what I missing in these functions or whether there is another solution in R for NW estimate.

Comment: This question seems to be asking for alternate algorithms which is more suited to the [Cross Validated][https://stats.stackexchange.com/] site. Additionally, the question seems to be "is there a faster or other way to do this", but you don't include any metrics about what "slow" is or why it's a problem. `mNW(x, X, Y, h = 0.5)` appears to run in 0.02 seconds on my machine given your example code which leaves the question: "What exactly is the problem"?

Comment: The question is about already existing functions in R which can satisfy my conditions. Note that example is very basic and for ilustration only. Vector `x` can be much longer which increases computation time rapidly. In such a case, naive implementation of `mNW` is incomparable to `ksmooth` or `locpoly` as they are way much faster.

Comment: Is your `mNW` the final function you want? because it can be easily translated to c++ with the Rcpp package. But if it is only an example i don't no of any other packages that implement the NW in R apart from the ones you mention

Comment: Well, if there is no other option, translation to C++ could be a way, however my experiences with C++ and Rcpp are very poor. In case you could help, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I coded your same example in `Rcpp` and it is way faster than the `R` function but it is slower than the `ksmooth`. Anyway it returns the 2 elements you wanted. I could not let the kernel as an input because it's kind of hard to do in `Rcpp` as you did in `R` but you can write a simple `if else` inside the Rcpp code depending the kernels you want to use ([here][1] is a list of the available distributions in R).

The following is the C++ code that should be saved in a .cpp file and source into `R` with the `Rcpp::sourceCpp()`

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<arma::mat>  mNWCpp(Rcpp::NumericVector x, Rcpp::NumericVector X,Rcpp::NumericMatrix Y,
           double h){

  int number_loop = X.size();
  int number_x    = x.size();

  Rcpp::NumericMatrix Kx(number_x,number_loop);

  for(int i =0; i<number_loop;++i){
    Kx(_,i) = dnorm((x-X[i])/h);
  }

  Rcpp::NumericVector row_sums = rowSums(Kx);
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix W = Kx*0;
  for(int i =0; i<number_loop;++i){
    W(_,i) = Kx(_,i)/row_sums;
  }


  arma::mat weights = Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(W);
  arma::mat Ymat = Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(Y);

  arma::mat m = weights * Ymat;

  std::vector< arma::mat> res(2);
  res[0] = weights;
  res[1] = m;
  return res;
}
```

I use the package `microbenchmark` to compare the 3 functions and the result is as follows:

```
Unit: microseconds
 expr    min      lq     mean median      uq    max neval
    R 1991.9 2040.25 2117.656 2070.9 2123.50 3492.5   100
 Rcpp  490.5  502.10  512.318  510.8  517.35  598.0   100
   KS  196.8  205.40  215.598  211.4  219.15  282.2   100
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Implementation of different kernels is no problem. However, when I run the code, it returns error `Error in mNWCpp(x, X, Y, h = 0.5) : Not a matrix.` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Adela Y should be a matrix

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. I guess this is the best I can get now :) At least I learn something about Rcpp.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `locpol` package which works much faster than by-hand implementation in C++:

```
library(locpol)
# weights
W <- locCteWeightsC(x = X, xeval = x, kernel = gaussK, bw = 0.5)$locWeig
# kernel estimate
m <- locWeightsEval(lpweig = W, y = Y)
```